# Windows Server 2008 Sytem Backup

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

I have WinServer 2008 Standard Edition installed with the firewall configured, IIS, DNS, php is installed also and among other things.

Is there a way to backup the whole system and actually put these configurations on other windows server boxes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also take a look at Disk2VHD (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415) which will convert Windows partitions on-the-fly to VHD files/volumes. This option might be a little "cleaner" than the native Windows Server Backup when moving the image (they both produce a VHD image) to another/different system.

Answer (score 1):

The native backup suite of Windows Server 2008 is [Windows Server Backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770266%28WS.10%29.aspx) that is incorporated in Windows Server 2008, with this tool you can Backup the entire System on another Disk attached to the system or on an Network Share following this [guide](http://www.bitwizwebdesign.com/Blogs/Bryan-Soltis/September-2008/Windows-Server-2008-Backup-to-a-network-share) .

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean putting onto different hardware with the same name (disaster recovery) or do you mean replicating to multiple systems with the same configuration to run in parallel?

For the first case (DR), you can recover a VHD image pretty much anywhere as long as you make sure the system partition you provide is at least as large as the system partition was on the source system.  I've done that a couple/few times successfully, though generally in the same model family (e.g. HP DL385 G5 to HP DL 385 G2).

-Mary